# How to Include HTML inside If Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why when I have certain HTML in my C# statements does Razor complain about invalid expressions and terms?

And how can I fix this?

For example; in my _layout.cshtml:

```
@if (Team.Id == ViewBag.TeamId)
{
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    &nbsp;
}
```

Comment: As @RowanFreeman has indicated, escaping the HTML with `@:` is one way around this. If you are able to provide more context about what you're doing (what is your data, what is your desired markup result), I'd bet someone could come up with a solution that didn't involve having to worry about this.

Comment: Another option would be to connect the end div to the start div, and vice versa. The code excerpt given is a bit anti pattern from where I come from as you are splitting a div at a at seemingly random place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Razor actually tries to understand your HTML. Unfortunately it can't be highly intelligent and recognise dynamic code or code outside of the expression.

Since

```
</div>
<div>
```

is invalid HTML, it complains.

You can avoid this problem by using `@:`

This forces razor to bypass its "HTML recognition", and simply print whatever you're asking for.

E.g.

```
@if (Team.Id == ViewBag.TeamId)
{
    @:</div>
    @:<div class="row">
    @:&nbsp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `@Html.Raw("YOUR HTML");` inside an `if` statement to add HTML code

Answer (score 0):

i use This syntax :

```
@if (Team.Id == ViewBag.TeamId)
{ 
  <text>    
    <div class="row">
    &nbsp;
    </div>
  </text>
}
```